# Creating a custom anchor tag helper with hash string support

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I'm trying to create a custom ASP.NET Core tag helper for `a` tag that supports `asp-hash` attribute. What that attribute is supposed to do is just append the provided value to the end of the `href` attribute.

`<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-hash="mainDiv">some link</a>`

would then generate:

`<a href="http://localhost/home/index#mainDiv">some link</a>`

I found the source code for `AnchorTagHelper` in this section in [asp.net github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/AnchorTagHelper.cs) but **I can't find a way to append stuff to the end of generated `href`**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No `asp-hash` attribute exists, but there is no need to make a custom anchor tag helper. You are looking for `asp-fragment` attribute:

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" asp-fragment="mainDiv">some link</a>
```

Comment: Stupid me... didn't notice that